# aligning jpanels in jpanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment, layout-manager

I want to make a dialog like

[image]

This is what I've done so far

[image]

The problem I'm dealing now with is the Grid Layout which "Table properties" panel has. What I currently dont like is empty space grid layout created. 
Can I somehow resize this panels to the size of the panels in prototype picture ?

If not, I was thinking to get rid of "GridLayout" and instead use "BoxLayout" with "Y_AXIS", and then create two panels with flowlayout, where first one will have "FontStyle"  and "Table Data" panels and second one "Selection Mode & Options" and Additional properties"?
If there's a better way to do this, please suggest.

Here is the code:

```
class View extends JDialog {

    View(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame);
        this.setTitle("Settings");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setModal(false);
        this.add(getPanelComponents());
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    JPanel getPanelComponents() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.add(borderPanels());
        panel.add(southPanel());

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel borderPanels() {
        JPanel borderPanels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10)); 
        borderPanels.setBorder(
            new CompoundBorder(
                getTitledBorder("Table Properties", Color.GRAY), 
                new EmptyBorder(5, 10, 10, 10)
            )
        );

        JPanel fsPanel = new JPanel();
        fsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(fsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        fsPanel.setBorder(                
            new CompoundBorder(
                getTitledBorder("Font Style", Color.GRAY),
                new EmptyBorder(5, 10, 10, 10)
            )
        );
        JPanel fsSubPanel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel fsSubPanel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel fsSubPanel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel fsSubPanel4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        fsSubPanel1.add(new JLabel("Font name: "));
        fsSubPanel1.add(new JComboBox(new Object[] {"Courier New"}));
        fsSubPanel2.add(new JCheckBox("Bold"));
        fsSubPanel2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        fsSubPanel2.add(new JLabel("Font size: "));
        fsSubPanel2.add(new JComboBox(new Object[] {10, 12, 14, 16}));
        fsSubPanel3.add(new JCheckBox("Italic"));
        fsSubPanel4.add(new JCheckBox("Underline"));
        fsPanel.add(fsSubPanel1);
        fsPanel.add(fsSubPanel2);   
        fsPanel.add(fsSubPanel3);
        fsPanel.add(fsSubPanel4);

        JPanel tdPanel = new JPanel();
        tdPanel.setBorder(                
            new CompoundBorder(
                getTitledBorder("Table Data", Color.GRAY),
                new EmptyBorder(5, 10, 10, 10)
            )
        );
        BoxLayout tdBoxLayout = new BoxLayout(tdPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        tdPanel.setLayout(tdBoxLayout);
        tdPanel.add(new JLabel("Show values as: "));
        tdPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Text"));
        tdPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Number"));
        tdPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Character"));

        JPanel smoPanel = new JPanel();
        smoPanel.setBorder(                
            new CompoundBorder(
                getTitledBorder("Selection Mode & Options", Color.GRAY),
                new EmptyBorder(5, 10, 10, 10)
            )
        );
        BoxLayout smoBoxLayout = new BoxLayout(smoPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        smoPanel.setLayout(smoBoxLayout);
        smoPanel.add(new JLabel("Selection Mode"));
        smoPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        smoPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Single Selection"));
        smoPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Single Interval Selection"));
        smoPanel.add(new JRadioButton("Multiple Interval Selection"));
        smoPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        smoPanel.add(new JLabel("Selection Options"));
        smoPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
        smoPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Row Selection"));
        smoPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Column Selection"));
        smoPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Cell Selection"));

        JPanel apPanel = new JPanel();
        apPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(apPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        apPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        apPanel.setBorder(                
            new CompoundBorder(
                getTitledBorder("Additional Properties", Color.GRAY),
                new EmptyBorder(5, 10, 10, 10)
            )
        );
        JPanel apSubPanel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel apSubPanel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel apSubPanel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JPanel apSubPanel4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        apSubPanel1.add(new JCheckBox());
        JButton colChooserTrue = new JButton();
        colChooserTrue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
        colChooserTrue.setBackground(Color.red);
        apSubPanel1.add(colChooserTrue); 
        apSubPanel1.add(new JLabel("Paint cells where the value is true"));
        apSubPanel2.add(new JCheckBox());
        JButton colChooserFalse = new JButton();
        colChooserFalse.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
        colChooserFalse.setBackground(Color.blue);
        apSubPanel2.add(colChooserFalse); 
        apSubPanel2.add(new JLabel("Paint cells where the value is false"));
        apSubPanel3.add(new JCheckBox("Cell Editing"));
        apSubPanel4.add(new JCheckBox("Cell Tool Tip"));
        apPanel.add(apSubPanel1);
        apPanel.add(apSubPanel2);
        apPanel.add(apSubPanel3);
        apPanel.add(apSubPanel4);

        borderPanels.add(fsPanel);
        borderPanels.add(tdPanel);
        borderPanels.add(smoPanel);
        borderPanels.add(apPanel);

        return borderPanels;
    }

    private JPanel southPanel() {
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
        southPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 0));
        southPanel.add(new JButton("Save"));
        southPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
        southPanel.add(new JButton("Close"));
        return southPanel;
    }

    private Border getTitledBorder(String title, Color color) {
        return BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(color), title);
    }

}
```

**Work of Spring Layout:**

[image]

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class DialogSettingsSpringExample {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Settings");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(layout);

        /* define Table Properties panel */
        JPanel pTableProperties = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout tpLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pTableProperties.setLayout(tpLayout);
        pTableProperties.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Table Properties"),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0)
            )
        );
        contentPane.add(pTableProperties);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pTableProperties, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties, -50, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pTableProperties, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        contentPane.add(btnClose);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnClose, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnClose, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnClose, -12, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        contentPane.add(btnSave);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnSave, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnSave, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnSave, -10, SpringLayout.WEST, btnClose);


        /* define Font Style panel */
        JPanel pFontStyle = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout tfsLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pFontStyle.setLayout(tfsLayout);
        pFontStyle.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Font Style"), 
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)
            )
        );
        pTableProperties.add(pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pFontStyle, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pFontStyle, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pFontStyle, 150, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle, 250, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableProperties);

        JLabel labelFontName = new JLabel("Font name:");
        pFontStyle.add(labelFontName);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelFontName, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pFontStyle);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelFontName, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, pFontStyle);

        JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Consolas"});
        pFontStyle.add(cb);              
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cb, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, labelFontName);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, cb, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cb, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, pFontStyle);

        JCheckBox cbxBold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        pFontStyle.add(cbxBold);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxBold, -5, SpringLayout.WEST, labelFontName);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxBold, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cb);

        JCheckBox cbxItalic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        pFontStyle.add(cbxItalic);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxItalic, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxBold);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxItalic, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxBold);

        JCheckBox cbxUnder = new JCheckBox("Underline");
        pFontStyle.add(cbxUnder);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxUnder, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxItalic);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxUnder, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxItalic);

        JLabel labelFontSize = new JLabel("Font size:");
        pFontStyle.add(labelFontSize);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelFontSize, 55, SpringLayout.EAST, cbxBold);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelFontSize, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cb);

        JComboBox cbFontSize = new JComboBox(new Object[]{9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16});
        pFontStyle.add(cbFontSize);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, cbFontSize, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, cb);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbFontSize, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, labelFontSize);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbFontSize, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cb);

        /* define Table Data panel */
        JPanel pTableData = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout tdLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pTableData.setLayout(tdLayout);
        pTableData.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Table Data"), 
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)
            )
        );
        pTableProperties.add(pTableData);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pTableData, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableData, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableData, 150, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pTableData, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, pTableProperties);

        JLabel labelSVA = new JLabel("Show values as:");
        pTableData.add(labelSVA);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelSVA, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableData);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelSVA, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableData);

        JRadioButton rbText = new JRadioButton("Text");
        pTableData.add(rbText);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rbText, 15, SpringLayout.WEST, labelSVA);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, rbText, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelSVA);

        JRadioButton rbNumber = new JRadioButton("Number");
        pTableData.add(rbNumber);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rbNumber, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, rbText);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, rbNumber, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, rbText);

        JRadioButton rbCharacter = new JRadioButton("Character");
        pTableData.add(rbCharacter);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rbCharacter, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, rbNumber);
        tdLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, rbCharacter, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, rbNumber);

        /* define Selection Mode & Options panel */
        JPanel pSMOPanel = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout smoLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pSMOPanel.setLayout(smoLayout);
        pSMOPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Selection Mode & Options"), 
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)
            )
        );
        pTableProperties.add(pSMOPanel);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pSMOPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pSMOPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pSMOPanel, 20, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pSMOPanel, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);

        JLabel labelSM = new JLabel("Selection mode:");
        pSMOPanel.add(labelSM);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelSM, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pSMOPanel);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelSM, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, pSMOPanel);

        JRadioButton rbSingleSelection = new JRadioButton("Single Selection");
        pSMOPanel.add(rbSingleSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rbSingleSelection, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, labelSM);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, rbSingleSelection, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelSM);

        JRadioButton rbSingleIntervalSelection = new JRadioButton("Single Interval Selection");
        pSMOPanel.add(rbSingleIntervalSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rbSingleIntervalSelection, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, rbSingleSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, rbSingleIntervalSelection, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, rbSingleSelection);

        JRadioButton rbMultipleIntervalSelection = new JRadioButton("Multiple Interval Selection");
        pSMOPanel.add(rbMultipleIntervalSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, rbMultipleIntervalSelection, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, rbSingleIntervalSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, rbMultipleIntervalSelection, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, rbSingleIntervalSelection);

        JLabel labelSO = new JLabel("Selection options:");
        pSMOPanel.add(labelSO);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelSO, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pSMOPanel);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelSO, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, rbMultipleIntervalSelection);

        JCheckBox cbxRowSelection = new JCheckBox("Row Selection");
        pSMOPanel.add(cbxRowSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxRowSelection, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, labelSO);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxRowSelection, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelSO);

        JCheckBox cbxColumnSelection = new JCheckBox("Column Selection");
        pSMOPanel.add(cbxColumnSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxColumnSelection, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxRowSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxColumnSelection, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxRowSelection);

        JCheckBox cbxCellSelection = new JCheckBox("Cell Selection");
        pSMOPanel.add(cbxCellSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellSelection, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxColumnSelection);
        smoLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellSelection, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxColumnSelection);

        /* define Additional Properties panel */
        JPanel pAddPropPanel = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout apLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pAddPropPanel.setLayout(apLayout);
        pAddPropPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Additional Properties"), 
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5)
            )
        );
        pTableProperties.add(pAddPropPanel);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pAddPropPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableData);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pAddPropPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, pTableData);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pAddPropPanel, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, pSMOPanel);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pAddPropPanel, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);

        JLabel labelPTC = new JLabel("Paint table cells where value is:");
        pAddPropPanel.add(labelPTC);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelPTC, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pAddPropPanel);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelPTC, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, pAddPropPanel);

        JCheckBox cbxCellTrue = new JCheckBox();
        pAddPropPanel.add(cbxCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellTrue, 20, SpringLayout.WEST, labelPTC);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellTrue, 15, SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelPTC);

        JButton btnCellTrue = new JButton();
        pAddPropPanel.add(btnCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnCellTrue, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, cbxCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnCellTrue, 25, SpringLayout.EAST, cbxCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnCellTrue, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnCellTrue, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxCellTrue);

        JLabel labelVTrue = new JLabel("True");
        pAddPropPanel.add(labelVTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelVTrue, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, btnCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelVTrue, 2, SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellTrue);

        JCheckBox cbxCellFalse = new JCheckBox();
        pAddPropPanel.add(cbxCellFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellFalse, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellTrue);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellFalse, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxCellTrue);

        JButton btnCellFalse = new JButton();
        pAddPropPanel.add(btnCellFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnCellFalse, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, cbxCellFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnCellFalse, 25, SpringLayout.EAST, cbxCellFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnCellFalse, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnCellFalse, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxCellFalse);

        JLabel labelVFalse = new JLabel("False");
        pAddPropPanel.add(labelVFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelVFalse, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, btnCellFalse);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelVFalse, 2, SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellFalse);

        JLabel labelATC = new JLabel("Allow table cells:");
        pAddPropPanel.add(labelATC);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelATC, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pAddPropPanel);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelATC, 20, SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelVFalse);

        JCheckBox cbxCellEditing = new JCheckBox("Cell Editing");
        pAddPropPanel.add(cbxCellEditing);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellEditing, 20, SpringLayout.WEST, labelATC);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellEditing, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, labelATC);

        JCheckBox cbxCellToolTip = new JCheckBox("Cell Tool Tip");
        pAddPropPanel.add(cbxCellToolTip);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellToolTip, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxCellEditing);
        apLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxCellToolTip, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxCellEditing);

        /* show frame */
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(550, 540);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `GridBagLayout` to control resizing weight of each component. When you do resize, components with lower weight take less space than components with higher weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at SpringLayout (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html). This layout manager lets you attach the edges (north, south, east, and west) of components to edges of other components. This also defines the resize behavior. For example, the following statement attaches the west edge of a combo box to the east edge of a label with 10 pixels between them:

```
tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cb, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, labelFontName);
```

Here is a sample program that implements your Table Properties and Font Style panels using SpringLayout:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.Container;

public class TableProps {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Settings");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(layout);

        /* define Table Properties panel */
        JPanel pTableProperties = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout tpLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pTableProperties.setLayout(tpLayout);
        pTableProperties.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Table Properties"), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        contentPane.add(pTableProperties);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pTableProperties, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties, -50, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pTableProperties, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        contentPane.add(btnClose);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnClose, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnClose, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnClose, -12, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane); 

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        contentPane.add(btnSave);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnSave, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnSave, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnSave, -10, SpringLayout.WEST, btnClose);


        /* define Font Style panel */
        JPanel pFontStyle = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout tfsLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pFontStyle.setLayout(tfsLayout);
        pFontStyle.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Font Style"), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        pTableProperties.add(pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pFontStyle, 20, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pFontStyle, 20, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pFontStyle, 160, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle, 250, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableProperties);        

        JLabel labelFontName = new JLabel("Font name:");
        pFontStyle.add(labelFontName);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelFontName, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, pFontStyle);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelFontName, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, pFontStyle);

        JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>();
        pFontStyle.add(cb);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cb, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, labelFontName);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, cb, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cb, 3, SpringLayout.NORTH, pFontStyle);

        JCheckBox cbxBold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
        pFontStyle.add(cbxBold);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxBold, -5, SpringLayout.WEST, labelFontName);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxBold, 2, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cb);

        JCheckBox cbxItalic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
        pFontStyle.add(cbxItalic);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxItalic, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxBold);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxItalic, 2, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxBold);

        JCheckBox cbxUnder = new JCheckBox("Underline");
        pFontStyle.add(cbxUnder);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbxUnder, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, cbxItalic);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbxUnder, 2, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cbxItalic);        

        JLabel labelFontSize = new JLabel("Font size:");
        pFontStyle.add(labelFontSize);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, labelFontSize, 20, SpringLayout.EAST, cbxBold);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, labelFontSize, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cb);

        JComboBox<String> cbFontSize = new JComboBox<String>();
        pFontStyle.add(cbFontSize);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, cbFontSize, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, cb);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, cbFontSize, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, labelFontSize);
        tfsLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, cbFontSize, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, cb);

        /* define Table Data panel */
        JPanel pTableData = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout tdLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pTableData.setLayout(tdLayout);
        pTableData.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Table Data"), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        pTableProperties.add(pTableData);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pTableData, 20, SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableData, 20, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableData, 160, SpringLayout.NORTH, pTableProperties);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pTableData, -20, SpringLayout.EAST, pTableProperties);    
        /* ADD OTHER WIDGETS */

        /* define Selection Mode & Options panel */
        JPanel pSMOPanel = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout smoLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pSMOPanel.setLayout(smoLayout);
        pSMOPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Selection Mode & Options"), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        pTableProperties.add(pSMOPanel);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pSMOPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pSMOPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pSMOPanel, 20, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pFontStyle);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pSMOPanel, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);
        /* ADD OTHER WIDGETS */

        /* define Additional Preferences panel */
        JPanel pAddPrefPanel = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout apLayout = new SpringLayout();
        pAddPrefPanel.setLayout(apLayout);
        pAddPrefPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Additional Preferences"), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5)));
        pTableProperties.add(pAddPrefPanel);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, pAddPrefPanel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, pTableData);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, pAddPrefPanel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, pTableData);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, pAddPrefPanel, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, pSMOPanel);
        tpLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, pAddPrefPanel, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, pTableProperties);       
        /* ADD OTHER WIDGETS */


        /* show frame */
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(550,475);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. SpringLayout takes some getting used to, but it's so flexible.

Comment: It is really flexible and I really like it. Thank you once more! Check above what I've done.